# Remove a list of rownames from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of entries:

```
testMat <- matrix(1:30, nrow = 10)
rownames(testMat) <- letters[1:10]
```

... and a list of rownames:

```
rem <- c("d", "e", "f", "i")
```

Extracting a matrix containing only the rows with names provided in the list 'rem' is easy:

```
testMat[rem,]
```

Following this logic I would like to *remove* the rows with names provided in the list 'rem' from the matrix. But

```
testMat[-rem,]
```

failes with `Error in -rem : invalid argument to unary operator`.
Why does that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `%in%`:

```
testMat[!rownames(testMat) %in% rem, ]

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1   11   21
b    2   12   22
c    3   13   23
g    7   17   27
h    8   18   28
j   10   20   30
```

Negative indexing works for numeric indices only.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know why positive indexing works but not negative?

Comment: @roschu Because a negative value is not defined for strings.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit long but you can do that :

```
testMat[which(! rownames(testMat) %in% rem),]

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1   11   21
b    2   12   22
c    3   13   23
g    7   17   27
h    8   18   28
j   10   20   30
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the options, I usually like `setdiff` for these kinds of things:

```
setdiff(rownames(testMat), rem)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "g" "h" "j"
testMat[setdiff(rownames(testMat), rem), ]
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# a    1   11   21
# b    2   12   22
# c    3   13   23
# g    7   17   27
# h    8   18   28
# j   10   20   30
```